# Change downloaded file name in chrome C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome

I want to download a file with chrome. I don't know the argument that changes the file name.

`Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = DownloadLink;
p.Start();`

I know I can use selenium chromedriver. but I don't want to use an automation web browser because it asks me Recaptcha.

Comment: Is there any reason as of why you want to use chrome instead of downloading directly the file ?

Comment: @Franck yes. I use chrome cookies. because before download, I have to log in to a site.

Comment: Well you don't seems to know you can do everything a browser does with objects in the `Http` namespace. Reading cookie is parsing the chrome folder and get the info. Login in a web page is sending a request with proper input. Download is a http download.

Comment: @Franck even it has a captcha?

Comment: If you have a captcha you need a user to select/enter the correct sequence. There is a way to retrieve captcha and send answer. We used to have a couple for our website scraping tool.